# customization of the apa-style with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm trying to help a friend who needs to use the apa-style for his dissertation. Two things should be modified since he uses the `\footcite` command:

1. The title (of the book) should appear in the footnote which is not the case by default.
2. The authors' first names should be printed in the full bibliography at the end of the document.

Does it make sense to modify the apa-style this way? If yes, how can it be achieved? So far here is what I have (quite a basic code):

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}          
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}    
\bibliography{mem}          
\defbibheading{bibempty}{} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
some text \footcite{report}
\section{References}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty]
\end{document}
```

together with whatever report reference in mem.bib. Should I have a look in the bbx files (or equivalent) to customize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The APA style uses the author-year (or author-date) citation format, while you seem to want the author-title format. So: No, it probably doesn't make sense to try and bend `biblatex-apa` to your liking. Consider to use the `authortitle` style shipped with biblatex, and use `\autocite` as main citation command.